# How to find mean(row)/var(row) for my matrix in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a 100x100 matrix of rgamma realisations. I need to find the x = (mean(row)/var(row)) in order to find the SD(x). How do I loop through my matrix for this? Please kindly help, I am unsure of R syntax

```
data = matrix(rgamma(100,4.623371,2.757291), nrow=100)

rowMeans(data)
```

Comment: esentially, each row is a realisation. I am now wondering if the way I formed my matrix is also wrong?

Comment: Your current data is 100x1 not 100x100...

Comment: i have edited nrow=100 is it correct now?

Comment: No. You can check with `dim(data)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a matrix `data` the following divides the row mean by the variance of that same row, for all rows.

```
apply(data, 1, \(x) mean(x) / var(x))
```

Comment: yes, this is it! thank you. and if I need mean^2/var, do I change the formula to apply(data, 1, \(x) mean(x)^2 / var(x))?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

First, to get a 100 x 100 matrix, you need an input of 1e4 (100*100). Second, you could look at the `sparseMatrixStats` [package](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/sparseMatrixStats.html) which has the functions `rowMeans2` and `rowVars` as well as `rowSds`. I'm not sure if you want SDs per row or total.

Comment: thank you. I am advised to write my own code and not use packages, is there a loop I can use instead?